# Last element of an Array in Clojure

Tags: arrays, clojure

Is there any simplier way to find the last element of an array in clojure except this function?

```
(fn [l] (if (empty? (rest l)) (first l) (recur (rest l))))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For vectors, use peek for constant time

```
 user=> (peek [1 2 3 4 5])
 5
```

For Java arrays,

```
user=> (let [a (to-array [1 2 3 4 5])] (aget a (dec (alength a))))
5
```

For a general collection, you can get the last item in linear time with `last`. It is defined similarly to what you have done.

```
user=> (source last)
(def
 ^{:arglists '([coll])
   :doc "Return the last item in coll, in linear time"
   :added "1.0"
   :static true}
 last (fn ^:static last [s]
        (if (next s)
          (recur (next s))
          (first s))))
```

Comment: Is `alength` constant time?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `(last l)` that works in linear time (http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/last)

Another possibility is to reverse your collection and take the first element:  `((comp first reverse) l)`. But that's rather slow as reverse returns a non-lazy sequence. Note: `comp` returns a composition of its arguments (functions) (http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/comp)

You can also convert the collection to a vector first and then apply peek: `((comp peek vec) l)`. This should have a better performance.

Another one: determine the length of your collection and take the last element `(#(nth % (dec (count %))) l)`.

These functions work for all collection types (e.g. vectors, lists, ...). There are no arrays per se in Clojure (except you want to use Java arrays).

Comment: `#(peek (vec %))` will not show better performance on a regular list. `peek` will show better performance on vectors than `last` (and about the same as `#(nth % (dec (count %)))`). `#(first (reverse %))` for all collections is just as bad a `#(peek (vec %))` is for regular lists because both imply a full traversal ; `#(first (rseq %)` would be better if the collection is `Reversible` but most `Reversible` collections are vectors, for which there are better alternatives.

Comment: That's right, however, In my opinion, Bfcm was looking for simple and alternative methods AND ideas for getting the last element. As Bfcm was probably talking about vectors ('arrays'), `((comp peek vec) l)` should have a better performance.

Comment: But then, if the concern is about vectors, why `(comp peek vec)` rather than just `peek` ? `vec` does nothing to a vector.

Comment: So you are on the safe side, as I wrote "These functions work for all collection types  (e.g. vectors, lists, ...)". They 'work' for all collection types, they don't 'have the same performance' for all types ;)